# Agregar valores de un json a otro con php

Tags: php, array, json

hola tengo este primer json

```
[{ "title": "Fruto prohibido", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": "Espacio alquilado", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": "Fruto prohibido", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": "Hercai", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": " Demasiada belleza", "name": "LATINA" } ]
```

y este segundo json

```
[{ "duracion": "2023/02/16 00:00:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 00:30:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 01:00:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 02:00:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 03:30:00" } ]
```

quisiera pasar el parametro duracion al primer json con codigo php para que quede asi

```
[{ "title": "Fruto prohibido", "name": "LATINA" ,"duracion": "2023/02/16 00:00:00"}, { "title": "Espacio alquilado", "name": "LATINA" , "duracion": "2023/02/16 00:30:00"}, { "title": "Fruto prohibido", "name": "LATINA" ,"duracion": "2023/02/16 01:00:00"}, { "title": "Hercai", "name": "LATINA","duracion": "2023/02/16 02:00:00"}, { "title": " Demasiada belleza", "name": "LATINA","duracion": "2023/02/16 03:30:00"} ]
```

como puedo hacerlo

Comment: El primero con el primero, el segundo con el segundo y así sucesivamente ?

Comment: si correcto ambos json tienen la misma cantidad

Comment: no veo cual es el problema...

Comment: cual se supone que es el problema en el codigo?

Comment: Buen día, tienes que mostrar tu intento y especificarnos el problema que te surge a detalle (en tus preguntas futuras, ya que te respondieron esta), en este sitio no realizamos tareas ni pedidos de código, mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), saludos.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hay que convertirlo en array usando `json_decode`, luego recorrerlos y volver a convertilos en `JSON`

Algo así:

```
$json1 = '[{ "title": "Fruto prohibido", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": "Espacio alquilado", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": "Fruto prohibido", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": "Hercai", "name": "LATINA" }, { "title": " Demasiada belleza", "name": "LATINA" } ]';
$json2 = '[{ "duracion": "2023/02/16 00:00:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 00:30:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 01:00:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 02:00:00" }, { "duracion": "2023/02/16 03:30:00" } ]';

$lista1 = json_decode($json1);
$lista2 = json_decode($json2);

for($i=0; $i<count($lista1);$i++){
    if($lista2[$i]){
        $lista1[$i]->duracion = $lista2[$i]->duracion;
    }
}
$json3 = json_encode($lista1);

echo $json3;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que buscaba

Comment: Porque respondes preguntas mal formuladas?... y no es la primera vez.